# Running node/lessc within a python wsgi application in a linux shared host

Tags: python, node.js, linux, odoo, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run an Odoo (openERP) instance in a shared hosting environment using apache and mod_wsgi in daemon mode, that means that I don't have superuser rights.

This application requires a less compiler to work properly and since the system doesn't have node/lessc installed I made a custom instalation of node for my user and added the binaries to my path. The problem is that apache is running for another user and I can't get the wsgi application to bash a lessc command.

How I got node and lessc working for my user:

```
export PATH=~/apps_wsgi/node/bin:$PATH
```

My python version is 2.7.10 and here is some more system info:

```
[admsolariza@web7695 ~]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.11.6-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 (mockbuild@Build64R6) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat Jun 17 10:32:49 EDT 2017
[admsolariza@web7695 ~]$ node -v
v6.11.1
[admsolariza@web7695 ~]$ npm -v
3.10.10
[admsolariza@web7695 ~]$ lessc -v
lessc 2.7.2 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Here is my wsgi script:

```
import sys, os

venv_path = '/home/admsolariza/apps_wsgi/odoo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
if venv_path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, venv_path)

project_path = '/home/admsolariza/apps_wsgi/odoo'
if project_path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, project_path)

node_path = '/home/admsolariza/apps_wsgi/node/bin'
if node_path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, node_path)

import commands
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("lessc")
with open('apps_wsgi/log', 'w') as f:
        f.write(output)

import odoo

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Common
#----------------------------------------------------------
odoo.multi_process = True # Nah!

# Equivalent of --load command-line option
odoo.conf.server_wide_modules = ['web']
conf = odoo.tools.config

# Path to the OpenERP Addons repository (comma-separated for
# multiple locations)

conf['addons_path'] = os.path.join(project_path, 'addons')

# Optional database config if not using local socket
conf['db_name'] = 'foo'
conf['db_host'] = 'bar'
conf['db_user'] = 'foo'
#conf['db_port'] = 5432
conf['db_password'] = 'bar'

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Generic WSGI handlers application
#----------------------------------------------------------
application = odoo.service.wsgi_server.application

odoo.service.server.load_server_wide_modules()
```

Content of the log file created by the wsgi script:

```
sh: lessc: command not found
```

What I expected was the lessc command being found and working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: If ``node_path`` is executable path, then you should be adding it to ``PATH`` environment variable, not ``sys.path``. Edit ``os.environ['PATH']``.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much. This problem bugged me for many hours. I thought sys.path edited the $PATH variable.